Is using native events to submit forms in angular bad practice?
I'm somewhat new to angular, mostly coming over from react.
Needing to submit a form to backend, my current and in my opinion simplest solution is as follows:
<form (submit)="submitPost($event)" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="author">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="author" required />
    <label for="content">Post:</label>
    <textarea name="content" required ></textarea>
    <label for="image">Upload an image (optional):</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

async submitPost(event: any) {
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);

    await fetch(`${this.backendEndpoint}/api/v1/create-post`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    });
}

I looked for guides and it was mostly with ReactiveForms, which would need me to manually create an object with properties for each field (which didn't even bind file input correctly, so additional boilerplate would be needed to set the file) or with ngModel, which (to me) has the same inconvenience of manually writing out class fields for each of the form input.
Would my approach be considered bad practice in the proffessional industry and if so what would be the optimal solution with industry best practices?

It's not the Angular way. Yes, in Angular, at least as Industry best practice, you have to create a reactive form and define form fields. A file upload can be a bit of a hassle, yes.

if forms are simple, template forms api can be good enough for you. all the existing html validations should work as you were using a usual html form=

It's not the Angular way, but it works and it's simple so nothing wrong with it IMO. The only caveat is that once you start adding more and more features to that form, you'll probably end up the Angular way in order to manage the extra complexity. So it's probably the reason I start doing things the Angular way. So I don't have to refactor them into the Angular way later. Also, if doing it the Angular way, it will be more familiar to present & future Angular devs working in the project. But again, nothing wrong with keeping things simple :)
